# Joining two 10mm twin and earth cables

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk

I've had an electrician install some new wiring for me for our new electric car charger. It is 10mm twin and earth. He's had to join two of these together, he hasn't fully finished yet, but I'm wondering if the join he has made is sufficient. I've attached a photo of his work.

The join is inside a void under our stairs behind some plasterboard. It will be taking a current of 16A for approximately 9 hours at a time. In the future our new car will be taking 30A. I'm a little concerned that this tape job isn't right. Any advice would be great. [image: pic]

Edit: Here is picture without the tape
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify where this is? Based on the wire colors, I am guessing the UK. "10mm twin" isn't a phrase I've heard in the US, so specifying a location is important for understanding local codes and regulations. That said, I'm surprised to see this work outside an electrical box and just straight spliced instead of twisted in a wire nut.

Comment: Yes sorry didn't think of that, it's in the UK twin and earth is standard electrical cables used for wiring in houses. Here's a picture https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=10mm+twin+and+earth&client=tablet-android-samsung&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjztbfevOjSAhWnJMAKHRymA08Q_AUICCgC&biw=1280&bih=800#imgrc=ABVypcfSEy-nTM:

Comment: I don't see how anyone could answer form that photo. The tape doesn't provide the joint (the electrical connection). It merely insulates the joint.

Comment: What is the size of one individual conductor? Googling shows the "10mm" is actually 10mm^2, referencing the cross-section area of the conductor, but is not clear if that's a single conductor or all 3 conductors in the cable. If it's a single conductor, that's equivalent to #7 or #8 AWG, which is overkill for 16A service, but reasonable for 30A service (though a bit oversized). If it's all 3 conductors, that's equivalent to #12 AWG for each conductor, which is OK for 16A service but way undersized for 30A. Can you measure to diameter of a single conductor?

Comment: 10mm refers to the cross section, but that's not my question, 10mm was stipulated by the charge point installers due to the longish distance the cable covers. My question is, can you just crimp and tape cables like this when such high currents are involved and is it safe / legal

Comment: Is the joint soldered? Under the tape?

Comment: No it isn't soldered

Comment: That being the trouble with taped splices.  Rather hard to inspect.   @HariGanti the expression is "twin and earth" meaning x/2 Romex.

Comment: The normal connection in the UK is a set screw type, not a crimp. You must join these wires according to your local electric code so contact the proper authorities.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen a qualified electrician leave twisted and taped up wires in 30 years on the job. And that is because it is a ridiculous way to form a connection. The tape will degrade over time and turn into a sticky mess. Put the connection into a proper junction box rated for the job, they cost pennies.

p.s. I could *nearly* live with it, if the wires were soldered and then the whole thing put into a box, but even then the tape won't last forever.

Comment: Thanks, are you an electrician? Do you know which kind of box is necessary for a 30A cable

Comment: @AdamB Search for "30A junction box". £1.55 for a heavy-duty one from Screwfix. The silly thing is that it would have been quicker to use a junction box than twist and tape the wires.

Comment: Those junction boxes won't fit 10mm cable through them.

Comment: I gather that the cross sectional *area* is 10 mm^2 so the diameter of the conductor would be 3.6 mm. Won't that fit in the junction box?

Comment: It's the overall size of the grey casing that is two big for the external openings in the box.

Comment: @AdamB You (or rather your electrician) can make the holes in the junction box bigger. Or use could ask him/her about using Wago connectors, which also have boxes available to fit them in tidily.

Comment: @AdamB just google 60A or 60 Amp junction box. We use these to extend shower or cooker cables occasionally if it's not possible to swap the whole cable (just ensure good access afterwards though, never bury these in the wall etc.). Alternatively get a 60a domestic switch/ fuse unit or small fuse board (better but more expensive but also the option to isolate...).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately if you're not happy then ask the electrician what other options you have. Personally (I'm not a professional) It looks a mess and there should be a junction box you can use to make that look a lot better. But don't be afraid to question what other options you have.

Answer (score 0):

AFIK normally one uses a receptacle in a box for supplying power to recharge an electric vehicle. The vehicle charger plugs into that receptacle. The receptacle and the plug will be rated for the current that the charger draws. The boxes are not rated for current, but must be of sufficient size to meet the fill limit given the wires and the receptacle. In practice, I would bet that a sufficiently deep box would meet the requirements and would fit in the existing hole in your wall. But if you would need a larger box, then enlarging the hole would be simple.

Comment: Thanks, this is getting ahead though. The charger is being installed separately at a later date. At the minute we are just installing cabling to get power to the garage from the house.

Comment: Is the garage attached to the house? Was the cable you have spliced to connected to a receptacle in a box at that location? Where is this hole, in the garage wall or in a wall in the house? You have spliced a cable that goes out of the wall. Where is that cable intended to go? Is it going to be surface mounted (in a code approved covered track)  on the interior of the garage wall?

Comment: @JimStewart A receptacle is only used for portable EVSEs. Many people opt for fixed EVSEs because they tend to offer greater power for the same price, in which case you can either get them in plugged or hardwired variants.

Comment: Hari, thanks for informing me about this. So would this crimp splice be be allowed if it were coiled up in a box? And would there be a cover plate with a hole in the middle which the spliced cable would pass through? And would this cable be energized all the way to the end, at all times?

Comment: Would the cable for a fixed EVSE be stranded so that it is flexible?

Answer (score 0):

I am a chartered electrical engineer, licensed electrician and contractor. It would be acceptable to:
(1) connect with the appropriate crimps. (alternatively, in my personal opinion, although not mentioned in the rules, it would be acceptable to twist the cables together by creating 2 hooks from the cores on either side, hooking them together and then twisting... this then provides a strong mechanical coupling NOT dependent on the soft solder.)
(2) Then soldered. (Crimp must be before solder)
(3) Heat shrink individual wires.
(4) Heat shrink the whole cable with internally coated adhesive sleeving. If adhesive loaded heat shrink is not available, as long as the cable is in a dry area, normal heat-shrink should suffice.